# Lubuntu. Can't play Vimeo

Tags: video, lubuntu

I now have Lubuntu 13.04 with Chromium browser installed on my Acer Aspire One D255 Netbook. I can't play Vimeo vids. I've downloaded the flash nonfree package thinking that'll sort it but no luck. I get the message "This video can't be played with your current setup". I'm wondering if this is an issue with Chromium? Help please.

This has now been resolved by getting Lubuntu restricted extras.

Answer (score 5):

I am running Ubuntu 12.04, though the following command did the trick for me:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is disabling hardware acceleration in Chromium. Open Chromium's settings, scroll to the bottom and select "Show advanced settings" then go to the bottom of the page and uncheck the "Use hardware acceleration when available" tick-box. Restart Chromium and try again.